# Pandas - How to create new columns and merge back to the existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as below

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,5,'Dog'],[2,6,'Dog'],[3,7,'Cat'],[4,8,'Cat']],columns=['A','B','Type'])

| Index | A | B | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | Dog |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | Dog |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | Cat |
| 3 | 4 | 8 | Cat |

Based on the 'Type' column value, I need to apply its own function(for example for Dog rows, call its Dog function and get the value populated in the C & D; likewise for Cat type, call its cat function and create C & D column) and create two new columns C and D returned from these functions.

Finally my dataframe should look like the below

| Index | A | B | Type | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 5 | Dog | Dog1 Value | Dog2 Value |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | Dog | Dog1 Value | Dog2 Value |
| 2 | 3 | 7 | Cat | Cat1 Value | Cat2 Value |
| 3 | 4 | 8 | Cat | Cat1 Value | Cat2 Value |

Column C and D are values returned from the functions. For examples here I have given like below.

The problem I face here is -

For each type of 'Type' column value, I am filering the rows and calling it's own function and getting the C and D column but when I merge it back into the original dataframe with left_index=True and Right_index =True, it is creating Column_X and Column_Y for all the columns and this is creating problem when I iterate for the next 'Cat' rows. Please advice how shall I approach this problem

Code

```
def ext_fun(x1,x2,i):
    if i=='Dog':
        #Do some calc to find c and d value and return back

        return ['c','d']
    if i=='Cat':
        #do some calc to find c and d value and return back
        return ['c','d']
    
for i in df['Type'].unique():
    df1 = df[df.Type==i]
    df1[['C','D']] = df1.apply(lambda x: ext_fun(x['A'],x['B'],i),result_type='expand',axis=1)
    df = pd.merge(df,df1,left_index = True,right_index=True)
```

Note: I have 10 to 15 types in the column 'Type' with hundreds of records in each type.  The values for col C and D are dynamic and require a function. So function call is required based on the Type column value.

Comment: can you give a (dummy) example of the `Dog` function?

Comment: Please refer the provided the sample code.

Comment: If you could write what "some calc" is, it should be really helpful

Comment: Some calc lines of code involves find c and d value. you could assume c=1 and d=2 for example. In the code samples return value I have given 'c' and 'd' as string value just for easy return value. you can change it to 1 and 2 respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to split and then re-merge the dataframes, you can use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'C'] = 'Dog1 Value'
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Cat', 'C'] = 'Cat1 Value'

df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Dog', 'D'] = 'Dog2 Value'
df.loc[df['Type'] == 'Cat', 'D'] = 'Cat2 Value'
```

Sorry for the values, I don't know which value you will use so I fill it with yours

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned more elaborately. I have 10 to 15 types with hundreds of records in each type.  The values for col C and D are dynamic and require a function. So function call is required based on the Type column value.

Comment: You have to provide more infos in your question, and also part of codes where you tried to solve the problem

Comment: Please refer the code I tried.